# Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for presence of element located using Selenium Wedriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]

Locator for this is correct, but when running it in Selenium Webdriver, I am getting the same error . 
I have used different kinds of waits like Implicit wait, Explicit wait, and Wait for Presence of element

```
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xp‌​ath("//div[@id = 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1']/ul[2]/li[1]"))); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id = 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1']/ul[2]/li[1]")).click();
```

Comment: share your selenium and html code

Comment: WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id = 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1']/ul[2]/li[1]")));
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id = 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1']/ul[2]/li[1]")).click();

Comment: Can you share the website?

Comment: Its *Shine.com* , clicking on Login Link at top right hand side

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 'presenceOfElementLocated(By locator)', use 'visibilityOfElementLocated(By locator)'.
'presenceOfElementLocated(By locator)' only confirms the presence of element in DOM, it  does not mean that element is visible or enable. But if you use 'visibilityOfElementLocated(By locator)', then it confirms the element is present in DOM as well as visible. If you are clicking the element you can also use 'elementToBeClickable(By locator)';

Answer (score 0):

> Its Shine.com , clicking on Login Link at top right hand side

You should try using `By.linkText()` to click on `Login` button as below :-

```
driver.get("http://www.shine.com/");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);     
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Login"))).click();
```

Comment: I would prefer using By.className("logedin"), as the link text can change if the page renders in other language.